# Is there a way to block a Programm with a Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows, service

Is there a way to kill a process in a Service written in c#

Comment: When it is not Windows Home you could use applocker

Answer (score 1):

You can create a window service that will check at a periodic interval if a process is running or not, and if it is running, you can kill a process by its name.

```
var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("processname");
if(process != null) 
   process.Kill();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your fast help. It works just fine now. I had to make a few changes on your lines since the GetProcessByName Method returns an Array. I now have it running like followed.

```
   Process[] process = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
        int numberOfProcesses = process.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfProcesses; i++)
            if (process[i] != null)
                process[i].Kill();
```

I now just make the if condition a time sensitive one like read system time compare it and then decide if you have to cancel it.  Thanks.

Comment: You don't need Length and check for null. you can use foreach loop to simplify this.